# Component not displaying using consumer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I correctly passed the data to the consumer using context api,
however the product component doesn't display.

Listofproducts component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Product from "./product";
import { Consumer } from "./context";

class Listofproducts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {value => {
          value.map(data => {
            console.log(data); // its returning the data correctly
            return <Product key={data.id} product={data} />;
          });
        }}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export default Listofproducts;
```

Product component where i sent the data with the consumer value:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Product extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.product); // not showing anything on the console nor an error
    return <div>hello from product</div>;
  }
}

export default Product;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your `Context.Provider` and `Context.Consumer` ? please read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: i have them , i will edit the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning the mapped data from within the `Consumer`  which is why your Product components are not getting rendered. Add a return keyword to mapped data and it will work correctly

```
<Consumer>
    {value => {
      return value.map(data => {
        console.log(data); 
        return <Product key={data.id} product={data} />;
      });
    }}
  </Consumer>
```

Comment: Adding a linter and code formatter will help you a lot in solving these problems. You could also use `Flow` typechecking to minimize code errors

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from the function given as child to `Consumer`.

Add the `return` keyword and it will work as expected.

```
class Listofproducts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {value => {
          return value.map(data => {
            console.log(data); // its returning the data correctly
            return <Product key={data.id} product={data} />;
          });
        }}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Anabe Great! I reverted back your last edit, as the error was already in the first edit of your question.